# What is the meaning of the color of the 'breakpoint' mark in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

When I set a breakpoint (double click the border of the editor at a particular line), there are 3 colors:
1. blue
2. faded blue
3. yellow with blue border

can you please tell me what are the meaning of each color?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Dark blue means "break point set, armed, and ready to go."

Light blue means "break point set, but you've temporarily suspended it" (perhaps by accidentally clicking it again)

Orange means "the code where you've defined this breakpoint is not (yet?) loaded into the program; once it does load in, the break point will be set and armed."