# Breakpoints dont work

Tags: xcode

When I set break point at some line and press Build&Go my breakpoints become yellow and my program continues. Nothing happens. I`ve unchecked Object Lazy ..., optimization levels, active target is Debug, load debugging symbols is checked. I also want to mention that my debugger never worked before.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924407/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-breakpoint-mark-in-xcode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working-in-xcode

Comment: I certainly know that this part of code is loaded due to NSLogs. So there is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Build and Debug" instead.

Comment: Thank you for response but I`ve also tried. This does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the files you are working on,  make sure you have build automatically set, clear all breakpoints, restart eclipse this might help.

Comment: oops never mind just noticed you were using xcode but perhaps the equivalent might help

Comment: Thanks but before trying I clean all targets.